# Difference between DATEPART "yy" and yy in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried with both syntax

```
select DATEPART("yy", GETDATE())
```

and

```
select DATEPART(yy, GETDATE())
```

Both are working. Are the double quotes(`""`) used for a special reason in SQL Server?

Which one is the proper use?

Comment: The **proper way** would be to use the **spelled-out** identifier instead of an abbreviation: `SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())`. And this identifier of which part of the date you're interested in does *not* have to be put into any kind of quotes either....

Comment: @marc_s yes exactly use the self-explained identifier is priority. But i was just confused that i SQL mostly no taking anything double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date part is specified by an [*identifier*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers). It can be specified with or without delimiters, hence `year` and `[year]` are equivalent. As long as [quoted identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql) are enabled, you can also use `"year"`.

```
set quoted_identifier on;
select DatePart( "year", GetDate() ); -- Works.

set quoted_identifier off;
select DatePart( "year", GetDate() ); -- Fails.
```

Note that [character string constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql) are enclosed in single quotation marks (') and may be prefixed with an `N` to indicate they are Unicode strings, e.g. `'Foo'` or `N'Bar'`.

Comment: That's the only answer so far that actually addresses the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can give

- year, yyyy, yy

All are returning the same value.And Microsoft didn't mentioned anything  about that double quotes.The above one is proper method.